# VBA Excel, shape array. How to fix the Error "Index Into The Specified Collection Is Out Of Bounds"?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, shapes

In Excel I have three shapes namned `ON_1`, `ON_2` and `ON_3`.
I am tring to  build an array of Shape indexes and get the ShapeRange.
I have the VBA code but i get an error which says;
The index into the specified collection is out of bounds. Here is the code:

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shprng As ShapeRange
Dim shape_index As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count)
For i = 1 To UBound(shape_index)
    shape_index(i) = i
Next

Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)

End Sub
```

I excpect to get variable `shprng` to include all the shapenames in the array.

But instead I get an error with this line of code:

```
Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)
```

> Run-time error 1004: The index into the specified collection is out of bounds

Any ideas?

Comment: The collection/array may start from 0 which means you need to use count - 1

Comment: hi, in this line ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count) it shouldnt be just ReDim shape_index(sht.Shapes.Count) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Sub test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shprng As ShapeRange
    Dim shape_index() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count)
    For i = 1 To UBound(shape_index)
        shape_index(i) = i
    Next

    Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)
End Sub
```

This line ...

```
Dim shape_index As Variant
```

... was your problem.  It wasn't originally declared as an array.

It's now this ...

```
Dim shape_index() As Variant
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both Louis and Skin for your  input. It now works fine. One question though. In what order does the shapes get looedp through? When I do I debug.print to check name and ID depending on the index nr (i) it seems like it loops through the shapes in the reverse order from what they are named:

Comment: @SweDentan that's a specific question that I'm not across the answer for but at the end of the day, if you're seeing that behaviour then it must work that way.  If you want it to work the other way, declare a for loop starting at ubound and step -1 to go back through in the reverse order ... which is your desired "correct" order.  Please also flag the answer you went with as the correct one, will help others as well as the person who answered correctly.  Glad you got your answer and glad we could help.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use these fixes:

- There's no need to use a heavy memory `variant` array. For your goal, a simple array of `Integer` will suffice.
- Check if `.Shapes.Count` is `0`, otherwise your code will not work
- (Optional) The actual array size can be obtained with `UBound(shape_index) - LBound(shape_index) + 1` (even if in this case it's not needed because you already know your lower bound)

With these corrections now it works. Here's the code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shprng As ShapeRange
    Dim shape_index() As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'If no shape is present, exit sub
    If sht.Shapes.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ReDim shape_index(1 To sht.Shapes.Count)
    For i = 1 To UBound(shape_index) - LBound(shape_index) + 1
        shape_index(i) = i
    Next

    Set shprng = sht.Shapes.Range(shape_index)

End Sub
```

Hope it helps.